# Is It Acceptable To Keep An Error Log Opened As Long As the Application Runs?

Tags: c++, file, stream, filestream

Is it acceptable, to open an error file output stream when initializing the application, and not ever close it till your application stops running? Can it occur the file will get closed automatically after a while? Does keeping the file open limit me in any way?

Comment: You should flush the output stream after writing to it to ensure that you don't lose any messages if the application crashes. Other than that, I don't think there's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it acceptable, to open an error file output stream when initializing the application, and not ever close it till your application stops running?

Yes.

> Can it occur the file will get closed automatically after a while?

No.

> Does keeping the file open limit me in any way?

No (well, it will count against your maximum number of open files, but that's not likely to be a problem).

Comment: But like it cannot occur that it will not be able to write anymore if the file gets opened by a text editor for example?

Comment: I guess that's system dependent.  What does your documentation say?

Comment: Usually, if you successfully open a file for writing, other applications can only open it for reading or not at all. But yeah, system dependent.